# Concise words for "completed" and "planned" tasks in meeting minutes

Tags: word-choice

In a weekly meeting you report what you did last week and what you are going to do in the next week. In a minute you record those informations.

> Worked on tasks this week: xy worked on ... and also he ...
>
> Schedule for next week: xy will investigate into ...

I am looking for some concise and meaningful words, describing *Worked on tasks this week* and *Schedule for next week*. Just *report* is too meaningless, because it could refer to everything.

An American word is preferred, but BE also works for me.

Comment: Are **completed tasks** and **planned tasks** not concise enough?

Comment: I agree. You can't really shorten those phrases without losing some aspect of their meaning.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Tasks that I worked on are not always completed. I think my word choice in the title (*done*) is misleading. And *Worked tasks* is at least odd or even wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @Em1: What's your first language? Does there exist such a word in it which would express what you're looking for? I don't seem to find one in either of my native languages (which are quite unrelated linguistically). I mean, maybe this kind of word just doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Complete** / **Finished** / **Done** are tasks that were finished in the past week.

**Ongoing** / **Active** / **In-Process** are tasks that have been started but are not finished yet.

**Starting** / **Next** are tasks that will be started next week (or soon, at least).

**Future** / **Unscheduled** are tasks that are known but which have no definitive start time yet.

Answer (score 5):

> Tasks that I worked on are not always completed. I think my word choice in the title (done) is misleading. And Worked tasks is at least odd or even wrong, isn't it?

In the past I've been on teams that used the following:

**Did(s)**: what you worked on (completed)

**To Do(s)**: what you  will work on (planned)

While maybe not grammatically correct, they are clear and concise, and worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

To describe things that you've done (but which you may not have completed), how about just "**activities**"?  You could pair it off with "**plans**" for things you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since worked on tasks are not necessarily completed I'd make a distinction between "Done" and "In Progress".

Scheduled for next week consists of two categories, the first thing you will do next week, "Next" and everything else "Upcoming/Starting"

Answer (score 0):

'Concise' depends on your definition. The following seems a simple and clear format to me:

> - **Completed:** 
>     ...
> - **Next:** ...

OR

> - Completed:
> - Scheduled: